# user/group/permission is need in Yii framework

Tags: permissions, yii, user-management

I am developing a project with Yii framework.

I need to organized website users in some groups to give them specific permissions.

I don't know if there is any pre-written module/extension for this purpose in Yii framework I have to write it myself?

would you give me some information about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a really good extension to do it: [Rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights)!

With rights you can:

- Assign some permission to a user
- Assign one or several groups to a user
- Assign some rights to a group
- Make a group heritate rights from an other
- And a lot more!

Comment: Yes, I'm using it on a website since 10 months and so far, no problem!

Comment: Just in case, I am using [auth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth) module. It is from the creator of the Rights module for managing user permissions in Yii.

Comment: Yeap I also switched to this one!